# Location of Wifi SSID configs and how to make a hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

What is the location of wifi ssid config in Ubuntu 14.04. Also, making a wifi connection as Hotspot does not work.

I am unable to make a hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04 via UI. One of the reasons that I found was that mode is set to infrastructure in the hotspot config and I need to change it. I tried locating the file in /etc/network/interfaces from online search but that configuration is not something that I am looking for.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with _making a wifi connection as Hotspot does not work._ without giving further details? This way your question will be closed on the ground that your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

1. The location for all the wifi connections is `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. You can find all the saved wifi connections to here in their SSID named files.

   To access the wifi configs, you need to be an admin user, therefore, sudo has to be used.

   ```
   sudo cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
   ```
2. To change a connection to make it a hotspot, you can go to the corresponding config file for the wifi connection and change the `mode=infrastructure` to `mode=ap` and save the config. This will make the hotspot work.

When you are editing the connection next time via UI (eg. changing the password etc.), the mode value is changes back to infrastructure. Thus, it has to be change to ap again in config.